# VBA - Comparing Layouts of Two Files

Tags: vba

I am trying to figure out how to check that the **layout** (not the full content) of a CSV file is the same of that in the preceding month (or, if that file doesn't exist, the last available CSV file).

Often companies change the format/layout of their CSV extracts, so I want my code to automatically detect any changes (new columns added, changing order of columns, etc).

Please let me know if you have an idea of how this could be achieved!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CSV import tools dynamicly determine the number and type of columns. What tool, application or library are you using for CSV import?

Comment: It can be done, if you would be more accurate in description of the task. Would you have the previous csv open and you should compare the new one with its structure? Would you have the previous csv column headers in an array? Do both files have column headers? Counting the columns and if equal checking each column position will it be enough for you to consider that the 'comparing' has been done?

Comment: Do you know the path to the csv file to be checked? What "if that file doesn't exist, the last available CSV file" does mean? Based on what the code to determine which to be the the reference file? Can't you open it firstly? Are there a kind of folders/files hierarchy being named according to a specific algorithm?

Comment: If you have the "final" list of headers in the order you want, why not just put those in an array and check each column and sort accordingly? What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you all and sorry that my question wasn't clearer! The files are being imported from online platforms, which can sometimes change their file formats from one month to the other. I have the code to be able to open both this month's CSV, as well as the latest available file. However, these are pure downloads from the internet so I am not naming ranges in them. What I want to achieve is to compare all column headers from the latest file Vs those of the second most recent file and ensure they are identical. Do you know how I could do this without named ranges?

Comment: I know, but I like to be sure that I understood what **you have** versus **what you need**. I do not care too much about the files provenience. So, you have a csv file in a folder you know that it should be there and another (open) file to be used like reference in order to check the structure. If I would make a macro offering the possibility to work with the reference (previous, any considered being appropriate) file **being active**, launching a browse window to select the file to be checked and returning the comparing result in a message (or something else), would it be convenient for you?

Comment: If you come here to check your question only one time per day, it will be difficult to be consistently helped, I am afraid...

Comment: This is so kind of you! I'm very sorry that I haven't checked your responses sooner. That would be absolutely what I am trying to achieve. Please let me know if you need any further information and thank you again for taking the time to help me!

Comment: If you do not tag me (@FaneDuru), I am not notified about your answer... It only happened I had this page open. I will place an answer, but your way of asking is not the most appropriate one...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It assumes that the csv to be compared is comma separated and ending lines are `vbCrLf`:

```
Private Sub CheckCSVfile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String, ans As VbMsgBoxResult, sep As String
    Dim arrRef, arrCSV, cols, i As Long, strProbl As String
    
    ans = MsgBox("Is the active sheet the one you wan to use as reference to compare the CSV file structure?" & vbCrLf & _
                       "If this is the situation, please press ""Yes""!", vbYesNo, "Confirm the active sheet as reference")
        If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
                       
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Put the first sheet row values in an array (2D array):
    arrRef = ws.Range(ws.cells(1, 1), ws.cells(1, ws.cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).value
    
    ''Browse for the .csv file to be checked:
    strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select the csv file to be checked.")

    If strFile = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
    'Put the content of the csv file in an array (split by the line ending separator). If not vbCrLf, use the appropriate one:
    arrCSV = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strFile, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    
    sep = ","                         'the csv file separator. Use here the correct one if not comma
    cols = Split(arrCSV(0), sep) 'number of columns of the first csv file row (zero based array)
    
    If UBound(cols) + 1 <> UBound(arrRef, 2) Then '+ 1 for the first array because it is of 0 based type
        strProbl = strProbl & "The number of columns in the new csv file is different (" & UBound(cols) & " against " & UBound(arrRef) & ")." & vbCrLf
    End If
        'Comparing each header:
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrRef, 2) - 1
            If UCase(arrRef(1, i + 1)) <> UCase(cols(i)) Then
                strProbl = strProbl & "The value in the column " & i + 1 & " is different (" & cols(i) & " against " & arrRef(1, i + 1) & ")" & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next i

   Stop
   If strProbl <> "" Then
        MsgBox "The new csv file has a different structure: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strProbl, vbCritical, "Structure problems..."
    Else
        MsgBox "The both files structure is the same!", vbInformation, "No any structure problem"
   End If
End Sub
```

You must firstly open and activate the sheet of the previous csv file (to be used as reference) and then run the above code.

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Comment: @Cla Rosie: Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: @ FaneDuru Thank you for spending so much time helping me and regularly checking this page! My PC has a screen scramble issue so I have been trying to work on this but the PC screen gives me a big headache. Sorry I have not been more responsive to you!

I am trying to test your code but cannot make the arrRef line work :( I get type mismatch, imagine it's because it wants to be an array, not a long?

Comment: @Cla Rosie: Did you run the code as it is? Did you keep the variables declaration as they are? Do you run the code on the csv reference file? Does your reference csv file have the header in the first row? If yes and your file does not contain something confidential, can you share it?

Comment: Good morning! Yes I ran it exactly as is but the code says there is a Type Mismatch on the arrRef line. I am so sorry but I have no idea how to share files! I'll try to figure it out now and send it to you asap. Thank you once more!

Comment: @Cla Rosie: You did not say anything about the headers row... In order to share the file you can use a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/). It is free and easy to be used. But, of course, you should share two such files. Named relevantly... Something like "reference file" versus "new file"...